# Switching betwen active and hot questions flickers another set of questions

Tags: bug, status-norepro

Can't reproduce this on other sites (n.b. other site had a Featured/Bounty tab).

To reproduce:

1. Navigate to the [Active Questions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/?tab=active)
2. Click the link to the Hot Questions.

Actual:

A different set/order of questions appears for a brief, split second, before a second set resolves.

Expected:

Switching tabs goes directly to that set of questions, without flickering other questions.

Environment:

Chrome 61.0.3163.91 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Variations:

```
c68ab9a3-3f4a17df
3095aa95-3f4a17df
7c1bc906-f55a7974
47e5d3db-3d47f4f4
2a33b90e-8c6be03e
d43bf3e5-bd7cd813
ba3f87da-45bda656
79616653-3f4a17df
5ca89f9-3f4a17df
9e201a2b-7e3ae057
5b3ed0a1-3f4a17df
68812885-4d2fac87
f347910c-3f4a17df
b791c1b8-3f4a17df
9773d3bd-f23d1dea
99144bc3-3cc2175e
9e5c75f1-40093a1
f79cb77b-3d47f4f4
27219e67-b2047178
23a898eb-aaaaf5b1
4ea303a6-ecbb250e
d92562a9-ca7d8d80
447469ba-ca7d8d80
7aa46da5-4ae2ba07
de03e059-e65e20f2
fbe6bb40-3d47f4f4
1354da85-489348db
494d8760-91c810ef
f47ae82a-86f22ee5
3ac60855-486e2a9c
f296190c-6e597ede
4442aae2-6bdfffe7
ed1d377-e1cc0f14
75f0f0a0-e1cc0f14
e2b18481-6754d7b7
e7e71889-e1cc0f14
644b8345-ca7d8d80
94e68624-f23d1dea
828a5926-ca7d8d80
```

edit: I can't reproduce this now. Same version of chrome. Caching?

Comment: I don't reproduce it with Firefox.

Comment: not reproduced on chrome Version 61.0.3163.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)